# Tomcat Sever is giving error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

whenever project is going to run on server. it is occurring followings error. this problems occurs after updating the maven.

```
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\SlickEditV18.0.1\win\;D:\app\Java\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;D:\app\Java\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;D:\JAVA UTILITY\eclipse-jee-juno-win32\eclipse;;.
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:OMTS_FINAL2' did not find a matching property.
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 910 ms
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\JAVA UTILITY\newWorkspace1\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\OMTS_FINAL2 does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4880)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5060)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/OMTS_FINAL2] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8181"]
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 22, 2014 5:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 718 ms
```

It is not running the project correctly what should to do.

Comment: Seems the first time I see this folder *OMTS_FINAL2*. Try to create one with same name if not exists or check its permissions as reported in error log.

Comment: OMTS_FINAL2 is also the name of project

Comment: I can see, sorry but long time didn't touch eclipse... Did you tried to undeploy/deploy the webapp and clean the server?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid spaces in between the docbase path:

```
.../JAVA UTILITY/...
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but still there is same issue